# I want to add a link for each task from my task index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my task index controller

```
 def index
        @tasks = Task.all
 end
```

This is my show index controller

```
  def show
       @categories = Category.find(params[:category_id])
       @tasks = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
```

This is my category index controller

```
 def index
    @categories = Category.all
 end
```

This is my category show controller

```
  def show
    @categories = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
```

It shows in routes that the path for `task#show` is `category_task`. But when I do this in my task index `<%= link_to 'View',category_task_path %>` I get this error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Tasks#index
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>"2", :controller=>"tasks"}, missing required keys: [:id]

How can I supply the missing key: `[:id]`? I already try to do `@tasks = Task.find(params[:id])` and do this `<%= link_to 'View',category_task_path(@tasks)  %>` it just five me a nil category id in my routes.

Comment: you need to pass both category and task to the url. `category_task_path(category, task)`. you also need to do a loop for each item

Comment: thanks @AhmedKhattab i got it . its working now